# Why does not WhereSelectArrayIterator implement ICollection?

Tags: c#, performance, list, icollection, toarray

In looking at **System.Linq.Enumerable** through Reflector i noticed that default iterator used for **Select** and **Where** extension methods - **WhereSelectArrayIterator** - does not implement **ICollection** interface. If i read code properly this causes some other extension methods, such as **Count()** and **ToList()** perform slower:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
{
    // code above snipped
    if (source is List<TSource>)
    {
        return new WhereSelectListIterator<TSource, TResult>((List<TSource>) source, null, selector);
    }
    // code below snipped
}

private class WhereSelectListIterator<TSource, TResult> : Enumerable.Iterator<TResult>
{
    // Fields
    private List<TSource> source; // class has access to List source so can implement ICollection
    // code below snipped
}


public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
{
public List(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    ICollection<T> is2 = collection as ICollection<T>;
    if (is2 != null)
    {
        int count = is2.Count;
        this._items = new T[count];
        is2.CopyTo(this._items, 0); // FAST
        this._size = count;
    }
    else
    {
        this._size = 0;
        this._items = new T[4];
        using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                this.Add(enumerator.Current);  // SLOW, CAUSES ARRAY EXPANSION
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I've tested this with results confirming my suspicion:

**ICollection: 2388.5222 ms**

**IEnumerable: 3308.3382 ms**

Here's the test code:

```cs
    // prepare source
    var n = 10000;
    var source = new List<int>(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) source.Add(i);

    // Test List creation using ICollection
    var startTime = DateTime.Now;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        foreach(int l in source.Select(k => k)); // itterate to make comparison fair
        new List<int>(source);
    }
    var finishTime = DateTime.Now;
    Response.Write("ICollection: " + (finishTime - startTime).TotalMilliseconds + " ms <br />");

    // Test List creation using IEnumerable
    startTime = DateTime.Now;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) new List<int>(source.Select(k => k));
    finishTime = DateTime.Now;
    Response.Write("IEnumerable: " + (finishTime - startTime).TotalMilliseconds + " ms");
```

Am i missing something or will this be fixed in future versions of framework?

Thank you for your thoughts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ to Objects uses some tricks to optimize certain operations. For example, if you chain two `.Where` statements together, the predicates will be combined into a single `WhereArrayIterator`, so the previous ones can be garbage collected. Likewise, a `Where` followed by a `Select` will create a `WhereSelectArrayIterator`, passing the combined predicates as an argument so that the original `WhereArrayiterator` can be garbage collected. So the `WhereSelectArrayIterator` is responsible for tracking not only the `selector`, but also the combined `predicate` that it may or may not be based on.

The `source` field only keeps track of the initial list that was given. Because of the predicate, the iteration result will not always have the same number of items as `source` does. Since LINQ is intended to be lazily-evaluated, it shouldn't evaluate the `source` against the `predicate` ahead of time just so that it can potentially save time if someone ends up calling `.Count()`. That would cause just as much of a performance hit as calling `.ToList()` on it manually, and if the user ran it through multiple `Where` and `Select` clauses, you'd end up constructing multiple lists unnecessarily.

Could LINQ to Objects be refactored to create a `SelectArrayIterator` that it uses when `Select` gets called directly on an array? Sure. Would it enhance performance? A little bit. At what cost? Less code reuse means additional code to maintain and test moving forward.

And thus we get to the crux of the vast majority of "Why doesn't language/platform X have feature Y" questions: every feature and optimization has some cost associated with it, and even Microsoft doesn't have unlimited resources. Just like every other company out there, they make judgment calls to determine how often code will be run that performs a `Select` on an array and then calls `.ToList()` on it, and whether making that run a little faster is worth writing and maintaining another class in the LINQ package.

Comment: Thank you - it's that pesky predicate that prevents it from knowing it's size in advance. I would make a case that process lists without making changes to their size is frequent operation and perhaps whereSelectIterrator can be a subclass of SelectIterrator which _could_ implement icollection. Anyway, thank you again.

Comment: actually, scratch that, reverse it: WhereSelectIterrator should be parent class and SelectIterrator should be subclass implementing ICollection